# Using the Foursquare API, can one verify who verified a venue?

Tags: api, foursquare

If users link their foursquare account to my site, via oauth2, when I pull a venue from the foursquare API would I be able to test if the current user is the same user who verified the venue (assuming the venue is verified)?

Or... is it possible to use the foursquare API to know who verified a venue?

I'm trying to build a service which venue owners/managers can use to help their business. However, I'll need a way to verify they are the owners/managers of the venue. I believe a very effective way to do this would be to force them to link their foursquare account, and then test if their account was the one that verified the venue.

If that's not possible, what's the standard way this is performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing if a venue is managed by the current OAuth'd user, would it make more sense to get all of the venues that the current user manages? You can do that through our [venues/managed](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/managed) endpoint.

Also in general, your approach of requiring the user to OAuth is correct and pretty standard for these style of apps. Our info on our [merchant platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/merchants) should be able to help you out.